# Problems with cacheing in apollo client

Tags: apollo-client

I have some problems with Apollo cache, ill describe the scenario:
I have a query,QueryOne that returns a data with a key named "getUserData"
And another query, queryTwo that returns different data with the same key named "getUserData", both responses may have the same key but the values are different.

That behavior causes my cache to get overridden, as far as I see Apollo saves key-value and not key-value per query.
I need Apollo cache to separate those two cached objects and understand they key might be the same but the response is different and is per query.

Can somebody point me to the right direction? Ive read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Graphql caches queries that have the same variables. For example

```
const {data} = useQuery(ALL_THINGS)
```

Calling the above query multiple times will return the cached results. If you add variables, and those variables are different, it will return normally.

You can force the query to ignore cache with this:

```
const {data} = useQuery(ALL_THINGS, {
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only', // Ignore cache
})
```